# gradient and derivative

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I am trying to find the first derivative of a Gaussian for an image (using Matlab) and I tried two ways.One using the gradient and one calculating the derivative but the results look different from each other.

```
  Method 1
  k=7,s=3% kernel,st.dev
  f = fspecial('gaussian', [k k], s)
  [Gx,Gy] = gradient(f)

  Method 2
  k=7,s=3% kernel,st.dev
  [x,y] = meshgrid(-floor(k/2):floor(k/2), -floor(k/2):floor(k/2))
  G = exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(2*s^2))/(2*pi*(s^2))
  Gn=G/sum(G(:))
  Gx = -x.*Gn/(s^2)
  Gy = -y.*Gn/(s^2)
```

Gx and Gy should be the same from the two methods but there is a difference in the values. Does anyone know why that is? I was expecting that they will be the same. Is there a preferred way to calculate the derivative?
Thank you.

**Edit**: changed the G definition per Conrad's suggestion but problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
 G = exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(2*s^2))/(2*pi*s);
```

Assuming this is supposed to the Normal density for (X,Y) where X and Y are independent zero mean RV with equal SDs = s, this should be:

```
G = exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(2*s^2))/(2*pi*(s^2));
```

(The term in front of the exponential in each component is `1/(sqrt(2*pi)*s)` and you have this twice giving `1/(2*pi*s^2)` )

Comment: :thank you for your response. I edited my post to reflect the change in G like you suggested but the results still do not match. Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of `fspecial`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html

[image]

so it seems that you should alter `G` to be:

```
G = exp(-(x.^2+y.^2)/(2*s^2));
```

Comment: thank you zenpoy. I tried altering the G as you suggested but the results do not seem to be affected, both methods show different Gx,Gy from each other.